# Creating a restful service in C# hosted by IIS

Tags: wcf, web-services

I want to create a restful web service that can accept json and returns json responses on a Windows server written in C#.

This particular service will actually have a long running background thread, so a WCF service hosted in IIS won't work (as far as I can tell, IIS will stop and restart the service on/after each request).

In general, I do not really even like WCF since I don't like dealing with generating proxy classes and updating service references down the road.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, with respect to WCF, is a technology already proven to help you build robust services, during your software design process you can design the service to keep state, hosting singleton instance, etc, so your impression of WCF services are somehow incomplete.

Now, regarding the restful approach, the technology used nowadays is called Web API, you can see some examples in the following website : http://www.asp.net/web-api , this will help you to avoid the tipical WSDL and generating proxies that you are talking about, and you can have bare-metal RESTful queries like "(http://myapp/orders/?id=1) that could return a json object with the orderid=1

Here you can have info for the instantiating mode in WCF services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you point me to a resource that explains more about not instantiating a new service for each request? I can't seem to find it